# How can I get characteristics with CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate to work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In a CoreBluetooth app, I would like to switch from notifications to indications, so that I can be sure that data is received on the other side.

In Apple's sample code [BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html), I tried replacing `CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify` with `CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate`. That didn't work. The peripheral logged:

```
2013-03-24 18:50:34.412 BTLE Transfer[15346:907] self.peripheralManager powered on.
2013-03-24 18:50:38.436 BTLE Transfer[15346:907] Central subscribed to characteristic
2013-03-24 18:50:38.440 BTLE Transfer[15346:907] Sent: Here is a bunch of s
2013-03-24 18:50:38.442 BTLE Transfer[15346:907] Sent: ample text. Hold ano
2013-03-24 18:50:38.444 BTLE Transfer[15346:907] Sent: ther device close to
2013-03-24 18:50:38.446 BTLE Transfer[15346:907] Sent:  see the transfer ha
2013-03-24 18:50:38.448 BTLE Transfer[15346:907] Sent: ppen.
2013-03-24 18:50:38.450 BTLE Transfer[15346:907] Sent: EOM
```

The central logged:

```
2013-03-24 18:50:19.209 BTLE Transfer[7331:c07] Scanning started
2013-03-24 18:50:37.998 BTLE Transfer[7331:c07] Discovered iPhone at -34
2013-03-24 18:50:37.999 BTLE Transfer[7331:c07] Connecting to peripheral <CBConcretePeripheral: 0x7591840 UUID = <CFUUID 0x7590780> 6A73BF68-01C9-B751-31D5-916297EC1932, Name = "iPhone", IsConnected = NO>
2013-03-24 18:50:38.001 BTLE Transfer[7331:c07] Discovered iPhone at -34
2013-03-24 18:50:38.030 BTLE Transfer[7331:c07] Peripheral Connected
2013-03-24 18:50:38.032 BTLE Transfer[7331:c07] Scanning stopped
2013-03-24 18:50:39.069 BTLE Transfer[7331:c07] Notification began on <CBConcreteCharacteristic: 0x75868a0>
2013-03-24 18:50:39.071 BTLE Transfer[7331:c07] Received: Here is a bunch of s
```

So it seems the central only got the first message, and then nothing more. 
Does anyone of you know what I did wrong, and how to get indications to work?

Answer (score 0):

hmmm maybe you need to acknowledge that you have read it before you can receive more? Only 1 transfer can be done at a time.

Comment: I checked that as well, there is no API to acknowledge receipt of a value update.